# OVM declarations inside connect phase

Tags: system-verilog, verification

I am looking for explanation/documentation on a particulare systemverilog/OVM behavior.

I have a class with a connect phase. Inside the connect phase I am trying to declare an ovm_object, although I have had some issues. When I do this:

```
virtual function void connect();
    super.connect();

    `ifdef SOMETHING_ENABLE
        ovm_object some_object;
    `endif
endfunction : connect
```

I get a syntax error, saying the following verilog source has a syntax error: "file.sv" token is 'some_object', and it points to my line of code with the declaration of some_object.

Although, when I wrap it with a "begin" and "end" I get no error:

```
virtual function void connect();
    super.connect();

    `ifdef SOMETHING_ENABLE
    begin
        ovm_object some_object;
    end
    `endif
endfunction : connect
```

Why is this? Can someone point to the documentation on this, and/or explain why I am seeing this behavior by the compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BNF for SystemVerilog requires that declarations come before any procedural statements in a block (This comes from Verilog roots in the Pascal programming language). If you look at the BNF for a function (section A.2.6) you will see that *{tf_item_declaration}* comes before *{function_statement_or_null}*.

In your second example, although you get no syntax error, you will not be able to refer to `some_object` outside of the block. So put your declaration before the call to `super.connect();`.

Comment: So when I add a begin and end block what section of the BNF does that pertain to? Would that fall under A.2.8 Block item declaration?

Comment: and  A.6.3 _seq_block_ and A.6.4 _statement_item_